# Why total length of all maximal repeats of a sequence S is $\Theta(n^2)$

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

Suppose that we have a sequence $S$ of $n$ symbols. A *[maximal repeat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_pair)* is defined as a repeated substring of $S$ so that if you extend it by 1 symbol to the left or right of it, this new substring is not repeated anymore.

I try to find an asymptotic estimate of the total length of all possible maximal repeats (overlapping is allowed). According to this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521585198) it's $O(n^2)$. Any insights as to why this is true?

Comment: This seems incorrect - imagine a vocabulary with $n$ distinct symbols, and a string $S$ such that no symbol occurs more than once.

Then, the total length of repeats is 0.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about your problem? Do you mean $O(n^2)$, big-o instead of $\Omega$?

Comment: @mxwsn Oh sorry about that, I fixed it. So, do you have any ideas why the upper bound is $O(n^2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider maximal repeats starting from $i$th symbol for some $i$, $1 \le i \le n$. Suppose that are at least two of them. Then one maximal repeat is a proper substring of another one, that is not possible by definition of maximal repeat. Therefore for each $i$ there is at most one maximal repeat starting from $i$th symbol. So there are at most $n$ different non-empty maximal repeats. Each of them is at most $n$ symbols long. Therefore total length of all maximal repeats is $O(n^2)$.